# Capitalization of title in scientific paper

Tags: capitalization, titles

I'd like to use the correct capitalization of words in the title of a scientific paper. The part of the title I'm not sure about is the following:

> What to do with an Area? ...

As far as I understand capitalization rules, the "What" has to start with an upper case letter because it is the first word. Area is being upper cased because it is a noun. "to", "with", and "an" are not upper cased because they are prepositions or articles.

What about the verb "do"? Should I use the following capitalization instead?

> What to Do with an Area? ...

According to https://www.santarosa.edu/~kthornle/30/CapitalizationMLAStyle.pdf I should capitalize verbs as well. My gut tells me that my second capitalization variant looks weird. Can someone confirm or deny? :)

Comment: Aesthetically, your first is better even though both Graffito's link and yours say to capitalise *Do*. I suspect it's because the key words are *What* and *Area*, with the rest present only as a form of scaffolding (speaking *very* loosely) to allow those two words their proper place and meaning.